# Объединить синонимичные метки {“шрифт”, “шрифты”, “font”}

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Объединить:

- [шрифт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%82) - 96 вопросов;
- [шрифты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%82%d1%8b) - 38 вопросов;
- [font](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/font) - 103 вопроса.

(по состоянию на 16.03.2017)

Эти метки нужно объединить, так как ими уже отмечены примерно соразмерные параллельные множества вопросов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделал синонимы, пока не стал объединять. Хорошо бы просмотреть вопросы и поправить метки.

Например:

- [google](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google) + [font](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/font) = [шрифты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%82%d1%8b) + опционально [google-fonts](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-fonts).
- Тут метка [шрифты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%82%d1%8b) вообще не нужна: [Как сделать фиксированный отступ до текста?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/633187/181472)